# How to use DB of Laravel illuminate's Database in Slim Framework

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model-view-controller, slim

I am using slim framework version 3. I have used Laravel's illuminate database. In my controller when I write below query it gives me error that "Class DB not Found" I have also specified use DB; in my controller inspite of that it does not allow me to write such mysql query.

```
$students = DB::table('students')->row();
```

This is my composer.json file content

```
"require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.0",
        "slim/twig-view": "^1.0",
        "vlucas/valitron": "^1.2",
        "slim/csrf": "^0.3.3",
        "slim/flash": "^0.1.0",
        "illuminate/database": "5.2.*",
        "illuminate/events": "5.2.*",
        "illuminate/cache": "5.2.*",
        "illuminate/filesystem": "5.2.*",
        "luracast/config": "2.*",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~1.0",
        "league/flysystem": "~1.0",
        "illuminate/pagination": "5.2.*"
     },
```

I have all necessary files in my vendor directory. But I want to use DB in my controller

Here is my controller code:-

```
<?php

namespace Controller;


use Slim\Views\Twig;
use Slim\Router;
use Slim\Flash\Messages as FlashMessages;
use Model\Student;
use DB;

final class StudentController
{
    private $view;
    private $router;
    private $flash;

    public function __construct(Twig $view, Router $router, FlashMessages $flash)
    {
        $this->view = $view;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->flash = $flash;
    }

    public function listStudents($request, $response, $params)
    {   
        $students = DB::table('students')->get();
        return $this->view->render($response, 'students/list.twig', [
            'students' => Student::all(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your controller code.

Comment: add `use \DB` to your controller

Answer (score 1):

You have to correct used namespace:

```
use \DB;
```

or

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

instead of `use DB`

Also you might take a look at tutorial for [using database illuminate without Laravel](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-illuminate-database-with-eloquent-in-your-php-app-without-laravel--cms-27247)

Comment: I have also tried use \DB; But class DB not found error throws

Comment: @Miteshkadiya added possible namespace with facade